# Clinical Device interface programming using ASTM protocol in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, serial-port, protocols, device

How can we implement ASTM protocol in C# to read data from Clinical Device ?
Can any one suggest open source framework to write ASTM segments ?

Comment: Could you provide a link as to the definition of ASTM?

Comment: ASTM abbreviated as American Society For Testing and Materials.Needed ASTM E1381-95,ASTM E1394-91 protocol implementation.[Learn more..](http://www.astm.org/DATABASE.CART/HISTORICAL/E1381-95.htm)

Comment: Hi Sridhar , Have you found anything on this subject yet ?

Comment: Do you have any success yet?

Answer (score 3):

I've been doing this since Mar of 2008 . I do not know one. Beside this not all of these diagnostic devices 100% compatible with ASTM 1394 . Especially package checksum calculation differs .

But I've infrastructures for Com port and TCP-IP level communications. Using USB directly is not commonly preferable because of the data-loss occurrences. Building an infrastructure for physical layer is logical. Because its a real standard but even for HL7 people use segments carelessly.In practice,this can happen; Lets put the patient insurance number to 11.segment ! But it could be 5 digits integer in standard. They don't care.

Have a look into this **http://makecircuits.com/blog/2010-06-25-astm-protocol.html**
But you should write on your own.

These guys are saying they had produced one which supports RS232, Bluetooth, HID, USB or network socket connection for ASTM 
http://www.deepsoftware.com/nrcomm/astm.html It is not free and probobly won't help for the varity reasons I shared. It says HID supported. HID is Human Interface Driver for USB as you know, just a few diagnostic devices use USB directly. Most of them use USB to send data to their inner central stations and provide you over TCP/IP. But some significant devices support USB directly but not with HID , they had coded their own drivers. Such as Welch Allyn's Propaq LT,its a handy monitor for US army use.

All the best!

Comment: Hi Davut Gurbuz, I am interested to know some thing about ASTM Protocols.Can you please help me regarding that

Comment: @Anjali: Once I've posted some info on LinkedIn. I think it is useful as the ASTM-introduction: [https://www.linkedin.com/groups/Good-evening-everybody-Please-Need-2069898.S.259238946](https://www.linkedin.com/groups/Good-evening-everybody-Please-Need-2069898.S.259238946)

Comment: There are lots of DOCS I have for Roche,Abbott,Beckman Coulter and for others. But As I mentioned there isn't a strict standard among them. You can find some more over the web ,such as this one http://www.inovadx.com/portal/Technical%20Support/QUANTA%20Link/QL_ASTM_protocol.pdf

Comment: Hi @ValentinHeinitz , I'm also a member of linkedin forum. I've seen your comments previously on the forum. Its good to see that some people share their know-how.For hl7 I use NHAPI (java version is HAPI) and it is very successful.There is a gap for ASTM. Maybe we can start building an open-source project for .net LIS developers on github. I formerly built a java and .net infrastructure for my company.

Comment: @DavutGürbüz +1 for HNAPI. Good to know for the future.

Comment: @DavutGürbüz could you send me link to your java implementation?

Comment: @briankip Since I've been giving consultancy in this subject I can not share free source code. I've generated a very well written lab-tested java based, HtML5 front end applied product. I'm planning to announce it later on. SOA is used and WebApi is enough for lab-equipment communication.If you know someone looking for professional consultancy or outsourcing please direct him to me.

Answer (score 3):

Be aware ASTM 1381 & 1394 protocol specs are now maintained by CLSI as LIS01-xx and LIS02-xx (https://clsi.org/standards/products/automation-and-informatics/documents/lis01/).  If I am not mistaken there are nuget packages available for [LIS01](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Essy.LIS.LIS01-A2/) & [LIS02](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Essy.LIS.LIS02A2/).

Answer (score 1):

Don't think there is open source available.
But you might check http://www.deepsoftware.com/nrcomm/astm.html

Answer (score 1):

the first step you need to understand ASTM, is that you have to work with Control Characters, , ,  these are not symbols, these are not string, these are not numbers.
so the first step in c# es convert these Control Characters

`static string enq = char.ConvertFromUtf32(5);
 static string ack = char.ConvertFromUtf32(6);`